# What are some cases / journals / books about withholding favourable evidence from the defence

Tags: united-kingdom, evidence, rules-of-evidence, disclosure

I have access to westlaw and lexislibrary but cannot find any relevant cases to the police or prosecution not sharing expert evidence from the defence at all. Any help would be greatly appreciated, even if it is not directly relevant. (UK Law preferably)

Answer (score 2):

### The collapse of the [Liam Allan](https://www.theguardian.com/uk-news/2018/jan/30/met-police-and-cps-apologise-to-man-after-collapse-of-case) case

Police failed to share exculpatory text messages, case collapsed after 2 years of bail and 3 days of trial.